# Gradle unable to find dependency

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, dependencies

Previously before I wiped my computer, I had a gradle setup that worked perfectly fine (android studio). I reset my computer, pulled the same project, and gradle was unable to find a certain dependency. It shows a valid on maven repositories: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.anko/anko-common/0.8.3

This is what my gradle looks like:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.{redacted}"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "@string/com_auth0_scheme"]

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'com.{redacted}'
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:auth0:2.9.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.diegodobelo.expandingview:expanding-view:0.9.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:108.5359.79'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    implementation files(file('../libs/emv-anet-sdk.aar').absolutePath)
    implementation 'org.apache:apache:29'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.8.3"
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.3.2'
    implementation(platform('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:5.0.0-alpha.11'))
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.11')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11'
    implementation 'com.github.davidmigloz:number-keyboard:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Gradle Error:

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.8.3.
Required by:
    project :app
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM, figured it out. I used double quotes instead of single. Silly me. Correct import should be:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.8.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

that artifact is provide by 'Spring plugin' or 'Spring Lib M'.
so you have to add repository.

Or, other version use.
other version(0.10.8) is exist JCenter repo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).